# NoReverseMatch using Django's url tag on template

Tags: django, django-templates, view

Someone give me some light here. I'm getting the error below: (using Django 1.7)

*NoReverseMatch at /cadastro/empresas/
Reverse for 'empresadetalhe' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []*

And my code is:

```
**mysite/urls.py**

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^cadastro/', include('cadastro.urls', namespace="cadastro")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)


**cadastro/urls.py**

url(r'^empresas/$', views.empresaindex, name='empresaindex'),
url(r'^empresas/(?P<empresa_id>\d+)/', views.empresadetalhe, name='empresadetalhe'),


**empresaindex.html**
<h1>Lista Suas Empresas:</h1>

{% if lista_empresas %}
    <ul>
    {% for empresa in lista_empresas %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'empresadetalhe' empresa.id %}">{{ empresa.nome }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Nenhuma empresa.</p>
{% endif %}


**views.py**

def empresaindex(request):
    lista_empresas = Empresa.objects.order_by('nome')
    context = {'lista_empresas': lista_empresas}
    return render(request, 'cadastro/empresaindex.html', context)

def empresadetalhe(request, empresa_id):
    empresa = get_object_or_404(Empresa, pk=empresa_id)
    return render(request, 'cadastro/empresadetalhe.html', {'empresa': empresa})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: django version 1.7 @sax

Comment: just a check. Is `url.py` a typo? The file name should be `urls.py`

Comment: Since your URL starts with /cadastro/, you're obviously including this urlconf from a main urls.py. Please post that.

Comment: you're right, just corrected that @sax!

Comment: use namespace, ie. {% url 'cadastro:empresadetalhe' empresa.id %}